# scope difference between document and document.cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a simple doubt here:

document object scope is within a browser tab: I meant If I set
`document.tab1 ='tab1'` in one browser tab It won't be available in other tabs.

But `document.cookie` is different, it persists across tabs.

But it is defined as a property of document, still if I add one entry in cookie from one browser tab, this entry can be accessed from other tabs.I understood like document object scope is within a tab.But here one document's property is shared between others. I know there are similar instances available for `document` or `window` objects, which are default properties or objects.

Why `cookie` like objects having scope across browser tabs, defined as a property of objects which have scope restricted within a tab like `document`?

Or correct my understanding.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please fix your grammar in the two crucial parts of the post, "*still how it is alive across tabs*" and "*Why these are defined like this*"; it makes it really hard to understand.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for the inconvinence. I updated now.

Comment: _“But here one document's property is shared between others”_ – the cookies themselves are _not_ a property of a “document”. `document.cookie` is just an _interface_ that lets you interact with the cookies for the current URL/domain. But that does not make the cookies themselves a JavaScript object, or bind them to the current document.

Comment: cookie property is for storage and it store keys inside storage. but when you create document.tab1 = 'tab1' it's just for current tab because it is not store inside storage. If you want to store then you can use local and session storage.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the replay. Then similar rule can be applied for `window.localStorage` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why cookie-like objects having scope across browser tabs, defined as a property of objects which have scope restricted within a tab like `document`?

They don't. Each tab does have its own `document.cookie`, `localStorage` or `window.name`. They run in different (JS) environments, as parts of different event loops.

Of course, each of those getters/setters accesses the same domain-, page- or tab-specific attribute that the browser manages, but it's just a JS interface to it; and as such it is located on some JS object in the JS runtime.